# An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near WHERE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I getting this error on the SQL code below, please help:

```
SELECT emissaogrd.dataEmissao, grd_dados.grd, documento.numero, emissaogrd.revDoc, recebimento.nome, grd_dados.usuariogrd 
FROM documento 
JOIN grd_dados 
JOIN emissaogrd 
JOIN recebimento  
WHERE emissaogrd.idgrd = grd_dados.grd 
    AND emissaogrd.idDoc = documento.id 
    AND emissaogrd.idgrd = recebimento.grdId 
ON recebimento.entregue='0' 
ORDER BY grd_dados.grd DESC, documento.numero;
```

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near WHERE

Comment: Um, each join condition, needs to directly follow the join it applies to. And each join needs a condition, not just a single condition for all. Please check the documentation.

Answer (score -1):

You're mixing old-style and new-style joins.  Should be something like:

```
SELECT emissaogrd.dataEmissao, grd_dados.grd, documento.numero
    , emissaogrd.revDoc, recebimento.nome, grd_dados.usuariogrd 
FROM documento 
JOIN emissaogrd
    ON emissaogrd.idDoc = documento.id  
JOIN grd_dados 
    ON emissaogrd.idgrd = grd_dados.grd 
JOIN recebimento  
    ON emissaogrd.idgrd = recebimento.grdId 
WHERE recebimento.entregue = '0' 
ORDER BY grd_dados.grd DESC, documento.numero;
```